# All my tables inserted with a .sql file are gone when I close a session in Postgres

Tags: linux, database, postgresql, psql

So I'm new to psql so sorry for the noob question. Not sure if relevant but I'm using Ubuntu 19.04 installed on a USB stick with persistent memory (used mkdisk). Everything works fine but I have issues with psql.

I have a .sql file that I use to insert all data into my database using \i <.sql location>. It creates the database called lepes_forms and inserts the data.

If I use \dt it shows all my tables and since I'm using this to display some Google Charts (which are doing queries on the DB) I know the data is fine.

The crazy thing is that if I close the terminal and enter psql again and use \dt inside the lepes_forms database it says "Did not find any relations", I lost all my tables, but somehow the data is still there because my Google Charts still query and load stuff just fine.

If I drop my database then Charts stop displaying stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Just managed to fix it, I had to edit postgresql.conf. I had to edit the search_path and add parameters based on my .sql file.

in my case it was edited to:
search_path = '$user, public, **auth_info, local, dados, estrutura**'

(In bold are my schema names that were added to the file)